# how to inject parent viemodel in child fragment in dagger hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

Using dagger hilt, how to access parentFragmentViewmodel in child fragment/dialog, also please tell me if parentFragmentViewModel is following @AssistedInject technique then how to access parentFragmentViewModel in child fragment/dialog

this is not working for me

```
private val userFragmentVM: UserViewModel by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })
```

it is crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside `onViewCreated` method of child fragment:

```
val parentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment()).get(ParentViewModel::class.java)
```